# Falsified student signatures in class attendance list

Tags: ethics, attendance

I am required to keep a tag at the students' attendance of classes by the rules of the university where I teach. The students' attendance cannot be lower than 75% of the classes, or else they automatically fail the course. To do so, I am required to handle them a signature sheet in each class. I am also expected to keep this sheet as proof I really taught the said class. (Not that I agree with this system, but the director can inquire a teacher and they must be ready to present this "proof", so I must abide by this rule.)

I have already come to terms with the fact that this is not really evidence of the students' attendance: they come late, leave before the class is finished, sign the sheet, and that's fine. However, even so, there are many absences and there is also the case of those students who falsify their classmates' signatures. I have already warned them on the first day of class that that won't be accepted, but in some cases the warning went unheeded.

The question is, I've had experience that the directors will also doubt the veracity of the attendance sheet, possibly accusing me of being too unyielding and uncompromising, even hinting that I must have falsified the whole thing with evil intentions. Because, according to the directors, a significant majority of the students must pass, regardless of their efforts. I have tried to be more "accepting" of absences (mainly if the student has good grades), but I cannot swallow having to condone falsified signatures. Should I follow the "culture" of the faculty that don't care the least about this fact (attendance and falsified signatures), despite their own rules? Or should I follow the rules and face the (possibly unpleasant) consequences?

Comment: Could you hold your nose when you deal with the attendance sheets, and focus your energy on improving student outcomes?  Is this an issue that is worth possibly endangering your employment status?

Comment: Honestly, you should start looking for another job.

Comment: @JeffE, I've already started, but as long as it takes, my soul is already sold.

Comment: @aparente001, that's what I'm doing. If it can endanger my employment status, I cannot tell (I'm a tenured professor, believe it or not); it's just mildly nauseating.

Comment: I have to take attendance to (35 in a class) and read through the list ticking them off. I used to pass round a list, but since Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck were often present - at least on paper - I dropped that. One colleague uses the panoramic photo on his phone...

Comment: Instead of passing an attendance sheet, I would suggest giving an extremely easy quiz (as in, "1+1=?"), with one copy personally given to each student.  (So if there are 40 students present, you should give out only 40 copies of the quiz.)  The quizzes should have the student's name and signature.  This should take care of the "one student, many signatures" problem.

Comment: How big is the class? If it's small enough you can identify the students, you could start adding your own initials next to the signature of students you see.

Comment: My method (well, a colleague's method that I use) is to announce that I will count the signatures and the students. I wait until they start working on an exercise and I do it quickly. If the numbers don't match, I stop everyone and call out the names one by one, crossing those who aren't actually here. I usually have to do this once at the beginning of the semester and never again. However the students don't automatically fail if the attendance is low, it's just used for when students actually fail and you want to see if they deserve leniency or not (if someone never comes to class, well...).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I've done that before. It almost works -- except that, as I said, attendance rates _vary_ during the class: sometimes I start the class with 30% of the students, and some students just show up to sign the sheet and leave (many, not just some, start leaving before the class is over).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, In fact, I often used the student's attendance to evaluate if they deserved leniency in homework or exams: but leniency is practically mandatory as per the semi-automatic-pass policy of the university. To give you an idea, one semester the students signed a petition against me because they'd gotten bad grades in 1 out of 3 assignments. I was pressured by the dean and the course director to pass even those who had plagiarized.

Comment: @Joseph - Have you ever experimented with having some interactive portions of class, and making notes of students who had positive participation -- as a way of *raising* a grade when it's in a gray area? // If you are being pressured to pass plagiarizers then I will give you the Official Aparente License to Be Bitter.  Just focus on whatever is rewarding for you and go through the motions with regard to departmental expectations.  In a corrupt *system* you cannot do problem solving.

Answer (score 7):

The system you're describing sounds like a bureaucratic nightmare to me (both for the students and for you; these things generally go hand in hand). I would therefore sympathize with (and turn a blind eye to) students tricking their way through it to the extent that is necessary to let them focus on the actual work. It's sad that they are getting free lessons in forgery when they ought to be learning something more wholesome, but as long as they *are* doing the coursework without *academic* dishonesty (as in, homework plagiarism), this should not count against them. A class is not a test of conscentiousness.

If you want to push your students to attend the class, there are other methods that don't involve automatic failure, such as giving mild homework hints in your lectures.

[Extended from my comment.]